# Why isn't my apache authentication working?

Tags: server, apache2, authentication

I am trying to set up apache2 authentication for a given website which can be found locally on my webserver. When I try to open up the website it states Internal Server Error 500. Then I put the content from .htaccess file into my apache2.conf file and now when I try to restart the apache2 service I get an error:

```
Invalid comman AuthGroupFile...
```

If I comment out that line, then I get another error:

```
Unkown Authz provider: dorian
```

What am I doing wrong? The /etc/apache2/conf/users.conf file contains the user dorian with a password that was generated by the htpasswd command, the /etc/apache2/conf/groups.conf file contains the following:

```
admin: dorian
```

Thanks in advance!

The apache2.conf file's content:

```
<Directory /home/peter/public_html/>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Admins only"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/conf/users.conf
        AuthGroupFile /etc/apache2/conf/groups.conf
        Require dorian
</Directory>
```

Comment: Related [.htaccess Error : Invalid command 'AuthGroupFile'](//stackoverflow.com/q/25773547)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exchange a single line in the file apache2.conf. This line can be found in the  tag that the user has defined. This will fix it (keep in mind I am using Apache 2.4):

```
Require user dorian
```

Comment: Where does one need to insert the text snipped? Maybe you could add the file name and the location within this file? Please, edit your answer to add the information.